# Using Apache Nifi in a docker instance, for a beginner

Tags: apache-nifi

So, I want, very basically, to be able to spin up a container which runs Nifi, with a template I already have. I'm very new to containers, and fairly new to Nifi. I think I know how to spin up a Nifi container, but not how to make it so that it will automatically run my template every time.

Comment: share code/template/what you tried

Comment: Surely the template is irrelevent? It could be any template. And I don't have any code to share yet because I don't know where to start.

Comment: @R.Dyer-Evans, the question is too broad. you can create a `flow.xml.gz` locally from your template and put it into docker container so nifi will run it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `apache/nifi` [Docker container found here](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi/) as a starting point, and use a Docker `RUN`/`COPY` command to inject your desired flow. There are three ways to load an existing flow into a NiFi instance.

1. *Export* the flow as a template (an XML file containing the exported flow segment) and *import* it as a template into your running Nifi instance. This requires the "destination" NiFi instance to be running and uses the NiFi API.
2. Create the flow you want, manually extract the entire flow from the "source" NiFi instance by copying `$NIFI_HOME/conf/flow.xml.gz`, and overwrite the `flow.xml.gz` file in the "destination" NiFi's `conf` directory. This does not require the destination NiFi instance to be running, but it must occur before the destination NiFi starts.
3. Use the [NiFi Registry](https://nifi.apache.org/registry.html) to version control the original flow segment from the source NiFi and make it available to the destination NiFi. This seems like overkill for your scenario.

I would recommend Option 2, as you should have the desired flow as you want it. Simply use `COPY /src/flow.xml.gz /destination/flow.xml.gz` in your [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

If you literally want it to "run my template every time", you probably want to ensure that the processors are all in *enabled* state (showing a "Play" icon) when you copy/save off the `flow.xml.gz` file, and that in your `nifi.properties`, `nifi.flowcontroller.autoResumeState=true`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer, can you confirm that all variables (including sensitives) will be included in the flow.xml.gz?

Comment: Yes, all variables, including sensitive variables, are contained in the `flow.xml.gz` file. If you deploy to a NiFi instance with a different `nifi.sensitive.props.key` value, the encryption key for the sensitive values will be different and incompatible. You can either ensure these values are identical, or use the NiFi Toolkit encrypt-config tool to migrate the key.